# Initializing dialog with class/object instance data?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a dialog and some of it's static text controls should be updated during runtime, the data, that is text, lives in an instance of the class object and is dinamicaly changed.

the class has a button or menu that start the dialog, but how do I pass that data to dialog if dialog procedure is a separate function independed of a class:

the class has the data:

```
class A
{
    public:
        int data = 1; // pass this data to dialog
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
      switch(uMsg)
      {
           case WM_INITDIALOG:
                SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATIC), std::to_string(input class A data here));
      }
}
```

Is the only way to make the data static member or is there some better standard prcedure to pass data to dialog from an instance of object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DialogBoxParam()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dialogboxparama) last parameter is passed as the lParam to [WM_INITDIALOG](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/dlgbox/wm-initdialog).
You can pass a pointer to your class there.

Comment: and then associate it with dialog window say via `DWLP_USER`

Comment: Yes, usually I create another structure in a dialog which contains data specific to the dialog, including that pointer.